# Getting a button to disappear when a text field is done editing, but switches to another text field

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

My `UIButton` is set to disappear every time my `UITextField` is done editing, I invoke the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method, and just have the button fade away.  This works fine, unless I switch to another textfield without clicking out of the first one.  So for instance, I'm on textfield A, and just tap textfield B, the keyboard still stays up, and so does the button.  I don't believe that there is a method that covers textfields switching like this, only when ALL the textfields are done editing.  Am I wrong? Here is my code:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
negButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
negButton.frame = CGRectMake(textField.frame.origin.x, textField.frame.origin.y, 37, textField.frame.size.height);
[negButton setAlpha:0];

return YES;
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
if ([textField isEditing])
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
     {
         field = textField;

         CGRect frame = textField.frame;

         frame.size.width -= 40;
         frame.origin.x += 40;

         [negButton setAlpha:1];
         [textField setFrame:frame];
         [self.view addSubview:negButton];
     }];
}
}

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
     {

         CGRect frame = textField.frame;
         frame.size.width += 40;
         frame.origin.x -= 40;

         [negButton setAlpha:0];

         [textField setFrame:frame];
     } 
     ];
}
```

Comment: How about using the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` that is called on the newly selected textfield to know that the user switched textfield?

Comment: So you're saying to make it disappear then?

Comment: How are you making the button appear?

Comment: Is that not the behaviour you want?

Comment: This should be `textFieldDidEndEditing:`.  (and not `FinishEditing`). Typo?

Comment: Also, is this by any chance in a scroll view or a table view?

Comment: It isn't.  Oh, and I'll fix it.

Comment: Well, the answer is that `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method **is** called even when switching from text field to text field (it is used when the text field resigns its first responder status).  If you want more help, please post the code that isn't working.

Comment: You're right, I just did a quick `NSLog`.

Comment: I posted the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the order that your delegate methods are being called.

Let's say that you are going from textField1 to textField2.

Once textField1 is already active and you click on textField2, they get called like this:

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing (textField2)
textFieldShouldEndEditing   (textField1)
textFieldDidEndEditing      (textField1)
textFieldDidBeginEditing    (textField2)
```

You are creating your **new** `negButton` in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` which over-writes the reference to the "old" button (beside textField1) by creating one beside textField2 and storing it's reference instead.  Next, you call `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` on the new button.

What you want to do is move your code that is currently in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to the beginning of `textFieldDidBeginEditing` so that the previous two methods act upon the appropriate button before the new one is created.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I had figured out a way before this, but this is a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are invoking the button to appear on the

```
textFieldShouldBeginEditing
```

method, which is fine, and you are removing it on the

```
textFieldDidEndEditing
```

method, also fine. Why you are not seeing the button disappear when you switch to another text box is because when you tap that text box, the **shouldBeginEditing** method is called immediately after the **endEditing** method, resulting in the button reappearing immediately after it is deleted.

This is the way it is *supposed to work*, and if you want it to work a different way, you will have to make the code specific to each text field

EX:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    if(textField == myField1)
    {
        //make button appear
    }
    else if(textField == myField2)
    {
        //Something else
    }
}
```

Voila!

Comment: Okay, so in textfield A, when it switches to textfield B, the button in textfield A stays where it is, but a new one appears by textfield B.  But, shouldn't the one by textfield A disappear?

Comment: Also, that still leaves the button up when you switch to a different view.

Comment: Well, I did assume that you are removing the button from the super view in your textFieldDidEndEditing method.

Comment: I tried that, it still didn't work.  I seriously don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I've debugged it so much and it still hasn't worked